# Hide scroll bar in Windows 10 App / Visual Studio x-ms-webview

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio, webview, uwp

**Hello**,

i'm searching for a code, that's hide the scroll bar of **x-ms-webview** ,still scrollable. Can't find one for universal/Windows 10 apps. I found one (**scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility="Disabled"**) for Windows 8, but seems not working and getting a error "**Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility' is not a valid attribute of element 'x-ms-webview**'
"

Microsoft Visual Studio

Javascript project

Thanks.

Comment: You want to hide the scroll bar on a web page that needs to scroll?

Comment: Yes, hide the scrollbar, but also scrollable.

Comment: How would it be scrolled without a scroll Bar?

Comment: it would be scroll by touch and mouse gesture. I too am looking for a way to do this.....